# how do to polling in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Post call. After the result I want to do another get CALL to check the status. But **only** if the status is FINISHED.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/doPostURL....,
        headers: {
            "x-csrf-token": sCsrftoken
        },
        success: function() {
        .. now I want to do the polling on the status
         jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/getStatusUrl ,
            success: function(data, textStatus, response) {
        // to continue only if status if Finished 
            },
            error: function() {
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: why you don't make your call on the success function?

Comment: The first call is POST then I need to do get call for check the stats . if the status is FINISHED I want to continue but it  could take time

Comment: "contentType: "application/json"," — You're making a GET request. There is no request body to describe the content type of. What's that doing in there? Are you confusing it with `dataType`? (For that matter, there's no `data` for the previous POST request either, so that won't have any JSON in it either)

Comment: sorry yes I will fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.ajax returns a **deferred** object.

You can do something like below. More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

```
var doSomething = $.ajax({
  url: '/path/to/file',
  type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
  dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
  data: {param1: 'value1'},
})
function doneCallback(){
  // Handle exit condition here.
  doSomething();
}
function failCallback(){
  // Handle failure scenario here.
}
doSomething.then(doneCallback, failCallback)
```

Comment: but there is no polling here

Comment: You can implement your doneCallback like `setTimeout(doSomething, pollingInterval);`

Comment: Just to add more clarity to it... Here's how it works: First doSomething is called.. once the call is complete, doneCallback is invoked... Inside doneCallback, we are invoking doSomething again after a certain polling interval. This cycle continues unless exit condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to export the `ajax` call to a function and use recursion to pool.

**Note:** You should have a max counter so that you do not flood server with infinite calls.

```js
var max_count = 20;
var counter = 0;

function getStatus() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET ",
    contentType: "application / json ",
    url: " / getStatusUrl,
    success: function(data, textStatus, response) {
      // to continue only if status if Finished 
      if (textStatus != "status" && ++counter < max_count) {
        getStatus();
      }
    },
    error: function() {}
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set your code in a function:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "/doPostURL....,
    headers: {
        "x-csrf-token": sCsrftoken
    },
    success: function() {
      doPoll();
    }
});

var doPoll = function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "/getStatusUrl ,
    success: function(data, textStatus, response) {
      //do stuff
      doPoll();
    },
    error: function() {
      //handle error
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to add logic in the sucess to check the status if the status if not what i need to call again to doPoll ?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I do not fully understand what you are trying to say.